# input form file twig symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

i have a little problem, i would like use beautiful form for my drop file panel, but in twig i try to pass information, i know attr class but for other i don't know

```
        <input accept="*" type="file" multiple class="absolute inset-0 z-50 w-full h-full p-0 m-0 outline-none opacity-0 cursor-pointer" id="announces_images" @change="addFiles($event)" @dragover="$refs.dnd.classList.add('border-blue-400'); $refs.dnd.classList.add('ring-4'); $refs.dnd.classList.add('ring-inset');" @dragleave="$refs.dnd.classList.remove('border-blue-400'); $refs.dnd.classList.remove('ring-4'); $refs.dnd.classList.remove('ring-inset');" @drop="$refs.dnd.classList.remove('border-blue-400'); $refs.dnd.classList.remove('ring-4'); $refs.dnd.classList.remove('ring-inset');" title=""/>
```

i try to convert with twig

```
    {{ form_row(form.images,{'attr': {'class':'absolute inset-0 z-50 w-full h-full p-0 m-0 outline-none opacity-0 cursor-pointer', '@change':'addFiles($event)'}}) }}
```

it's good for @change??? someone help me, thank u!!

Comment: I think in this case I would use your first html input and I would add the name attribute value generated by the form_row()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I prefer to do is add a class in my form type. It prevent me the day when my variables "images" change to not impact the js.

"js-images-on-change" for example.

and in my javascript

```
$('.js-images-on-change').on('change', function() {
  addFiles($(this))
}
```